# Schematron Peppol validation

Tags: java, saxon, schematron

I'm using 'com.helger.schematron:ph-schematron-pure:7.1.0' and I'm trying to valid my peppol xml agains the schematron file 'CEN-EN16931-UBL.sch'

Here my code to valid and outpout the errors:

```
        final var res = SchematronResourcePure.fromFile(new File("CEN-EN16931-UBL.sch"));
        //if (!res.isValidSchematron())
        //    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Schematron!");
        res.setErrorHandler(new IPSErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleError(@Nonnull final IError aError) {

                System.out.println(aError.toString());
            }
        });            
        final SchematronOutputType schematronOutputType = res.applySchematronValidationToSVRL(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        SVRLHelper.getAllFailedAssertions(schematronOutputType);
```

But I get an NullPointerException. Any idea from where this "null" is coming ?

```
15:17:00.219 [main] DEBUG com.helger.commons.lang.ServiceLoaderHelper - Finished retrieving all 1 SPI implementations of interface com.helger.commons.hashcode.IHashCodeImplementationRegistrarSPI
15:17:00.235 [main] DEBUG com.helger.commons.hashcode.HashCodeImplementationRegistry - Reinitialized com.helger.commons.hashcode.HashCodeImplementationRegistry
15:17:00.793 [main] DEBUG com.helger.schematron.pure.preprocess.PSPreprocessor - Schematron does not need any preprocessing. Returning Schema as-is.
15:17:00.805 [main] DEBUG com.helger.schematron.pure.bound.xpath.PSXPathBoundSchema - Binding pure Schematron
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "net.sf.saxon.value.AtomicValue.equals(Object)" because "a" is null
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.GenericAtomicComparer.lambda$makeAtomicComparisonFunction$6(GenericAtomicComparer.java:248)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.ValueComparison$ValueComparisonElaborator.lambda$elaborateForBoolean$4(ValueComparison.java:620)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.FilterExpression$FilterExprElaborator$SimpleFilteredIterator.next(FilterExpression.java:1391)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceTool.supply(SequenceTool.java:145)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.DocumentOrderIterator.<init>(DocumentOrderIterator.java:41)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.DocumentSorter$DocumentSorterElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPull$0(DocumentSorter.java:331)
    at net.sf.saxon.functions.Count$CountFnElaborator.lambda$elaborateForItem$0(Count.java:135)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.ValueComparison$ValueComparisonElaborator.lambda$elaborateForBoolean$4(ValueComparison.java:620)
    at net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:181)
    at com.helger.schematron.pure.xpath.XPathEvaluationHelper.evaluate(XPathEvaluationHelper.java:63)
    at com.helger.schematron.pure.xpath.XPathEvaluationHelper.evaluateAsBoolean(XPathEvaluationHelper.java:70)
    at com.helger.schematron.pure.bound.xpath.PSXPathBoundSchema._validateSerial(PSXPathBoundSchema.java:739)
    at com.helger.schematron.pure.bound.xpath.PSXPathBoundSchema.validate(PSXPathBoundSchema.java:807)
    at com.helger.schematron.pure.bound.AbstractPSBoundSchema.validateComplete(AbstractPSBoundSchema.java:259)
    at com.helger.schematron.pure.SchematronResourcePure.applySchematronValidationToSVRL(SchematronResourcePure.java:394)
    at com.helger.schematron.AbstractSchematronResource.applySchematronValidationToSVRL(AbstractSchematronResource.java:286)
```

Comment: It is hard to tell without more details whether this is a bug in the Schematron library you use, its interaction with the Saxon HE library it seems to rely on or a bug in Saxon itself. I would suggest to file a bug or support report on the library producer. If you want to experiment on your own, it seems the 7.1.0 version uses Saxon 12, while 7.0.1 uses Saxon 11 (stable branch), so for testing you could check whether your code runs through with 7.0.1. As an alternative, of course with e.g. Schxslt there are other Schematron implementations for Java https://github.com/schxslt/schxslt

Comment: Perhaps @PhilipHelger can tell you more.

Comment: His repository seems to be at https://github.com/phax/ph-schematron so perhaps raise an issue there with all the details allowing him tell whether it is a bug in his implementation or some other problem he could fix or just a problem with your schematron schema or instance document.

Comment: The relevant Saxon code is at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_0/entry/src/main/java/net/sf/saxon/expr/sort/GenericAtomicComparer.java#L248, I think, creating a lambda `return (a, b, context) -> a.equals(b);`, the error suggests `a` is null. Hard to tell why that occurs without the sample data triggering the error.

Comment: The Saxon code seems to be used from https://github.com/phax/ph-schematron/blob/ph-schematron-parent-pom-7.1.0/ph-schematron-pure/src/main/java/com/helger/schematron/pure/xpath/XPathEvaluationHelper.java#L49.

Answer (score 1):

A NullPointerException deep in Saxon code is *prima facie* a bug: even if the caller did something wrong, we should have detected it earlier and produced better diagnostics.

The most likely explanation for an NPE at this place in the code is that some expression evaluated to an empty sequence, and Saxon didn't check for this because its static analysis suggested that an empty result wasn't possible at that point.

Happy to look at it if you can construct a repro and submit it at saxonica.plan.io.